# How to change controller RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, routes

I'm writing some tests for my simple Ruby on Rails application and found myself needing to use the POST method for one controller inside of another controller's test.rb file. The error I receive informs me that no such route exists and that is because it is trying to use the controller pertaining to the test file. I want to manually define a different controller for this one call to POST.

```
test "Rcomment - Destroy" do
    article = articles(:valid)
    article.save
    comment = comments(:valid)
    comment.save
    post :create, article_id: article.id, comment: comment.attributes
    post :create, article.attributes <--- "Should use article controller not comments controller"
    get(:destroy, { 'id' => comment.id, 'article_id' => article.id}, nil)
    assert_response :redirect
    assert_not_nil assigns(:comment)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

A controller test (that is one that sublclasses from ActionController::TestCase) can only test one controller class, and should only really be making a single request

If you want to make multiple requests across multiple controllers then you should use an integration test. If (as it looks) you are just trying to create some test data for your test then you can just create the data directly. By the looks of it it looks like you're using fixtures - You don't need to do a post to create those a second time.